# How do i assign profile2 (user) to a organic group?

Tags: nodes, organic-groups, users

Hello i am currently using a called Module Profile 2 to enable users to register and create profiles.

Also i want users to be able to create and join groups for which i am using organic groups.

But i have encountered a minor problem ....the request group membership is working for me but it only assigns the group in default user page not to the "Main profile" created using profile2.

Any solutions ?

Also i did find out [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/programmatically-assign-a-node-to-an-organic-group) solution which schnippy answered but being new learner to drupal and this web devlopment stuff am completely lost....is it the solution and if yes then how do i implement it ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried profile2_og_access? Its a part of the profile2 module, but has to be enabled separately.

Comment: Are you talking about Profile2 Privacy Module, that allows users to create predefined groups or sets of profile field ?.... If no then can u please post a link of the module u referring to ?

Comment: No, its not the profile2 Privacy module. When you download the profile2 module, goto _admin/modules_, under _Organic groups_, you should find a _Profile2 group access_. http://i.imgur.com/zGo6c.png