# Is it possible to attach a specific user profile to an organic group?

Tags: organic-groups, users

I want to have 2 seperate user profiles. One profile with a user picture and one without a user picture.
These user profiles shall be attached to a specific organic group.

I also need extra information stored with the help of the profile2 profile2 module. This question is similar to [How do i assign profile2 (user) to a organic group?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24295/how-do-i-assign-profile2-user-to-a-organic-group)