# How do I programatically add a Node to an Organic Group in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

This [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/programmatically-assign-a-node-to-an-organic-group) and the documentation would suggest that the [og_group](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_group/7) function is the way to achieve this; however, calling og_group thus:

```
$values = array('entity_type' => 'node', 'entity' => $node);
og_group($gid, $values);
node_save($node);
```

Does not update the group_audience field on the node.

I'm referring to 7.x-1.3 of the og module; currently the only stable release on D7.

How can I go about programmatically adding a node to a group?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's likely that the below is the preferred way to do this, however:

```
$node->group_audience[$node->language][] = array(
                                           'gid' => $gid, 
                                           'created' => REQUEST_TIME, 
                                           'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE);
$new_node = node_save($node);
```

Appears to update the node field and create the necessary entries in OG's tables unlike a call to og_group.

I'm open to a solution more in line with best practices but for now this may work.

Answer (score 1):

Try og_set_association() its listed under their API section of [og.module](http://drupalcode.org/project/og.git/blob/HEAD:/og/og.module)

I have done this in the past with D7, but I believe the API I used has changed since then.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks very promising, unfortunately it's only on 2.x dev branch.

Answer (score 0):

No, you use og_group() and pass $values as the third parameter that define your group content node, basically:

```
$values = array('entity_type' => 'node', 'entity' => $nid);
// Then call og_group telling it about your node.
og_group('group_content', $a_group_gid, $values);
```

The code you mention sets up defaults for og_group() to work on Users by default, as a convenience, you just tell og_group() to subsribe nodes of whatever NIDs.

The documentation says:

> $values: Array with the information to pass along, until it is
>   processed in the field handlers.
>
> "entity_type": Optional; The entity type (e.g. "node" or "user").
>   Defaults to 'user'
>
> "entity": Optional; The entity object or entity Id
>   to set the association. Defaults to the current user if the
>   $entity_type property is set to 'user'.
>
> "field_name": The name of the field, the membership should
>   be registered in. If no value given, a first field with the
>   correct membership type will be used. If no field found,
>   an execpetion will be thrown.

Comment: I understand that it is defaulting to users out of convenience. The problem is that the code I included above is overriding the $values array. This function returns a user object even when passing it a node. I've edited the above code to show more of the og_group function.

Comment: Hi, you're calling it wrong. += does not overwrite keys that exist in $values passed into the function. += is setting keys in the $values array that do not already exist. This may help [Gist Example for Domain 7.x-1.x very old](https://gist.github.com/2039318)

Comment: Your right, I assumed that was an array_merge shorthand. Thanks for the follow up. I've restated the question as the grouped node's audience does not change after calling og_group.

Comment: alright, if you call og_group() it adds the node/entity into the group -- it doesn't remove it from groups it's already apart of, you would have to call a different OG api call to remove it from group(s). I believe you have to call node_save() as I did in the Gist to make the changes actually be saved to the node. Lastly, there is a different between the Group and "Group Content", be sure you are passing the correct $gid around. Anyways, hopes this all helped. goodnight :)

Comment: Removing the node from a group is not a priority for me at this moment.  I'm simply trying to prove that I can add the node to a group. Calls to og_group do not update the node's group_audience field at all, that is my concern. Have a good night.