# How to assign nodes to an organic group in code

Tags: organic-groups

How can I assign a node to an organic group in code?
After consulting following page

- http://www.barnettech.com/content/adding-node-organic-group-programmatically
- [Programmatically assign a node to an organic group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/programmatically-assign-a-node-to-an-organic-group)

And de OG API I ended up with this code, but it throws an error 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'

```
$node = node_load(5827);
$values = array('entity type' => 'node', 'entity' => $node, 'field_name' =>'og_group_ref');
og_group('node', 3, $values);
node_save($node);
```

More info:
OG-7.2.7

Comment: Check the watchdog, it will contain the real error message

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It seems like it want to add it to a user type instead of a node group type.
   OgException: OG membership can not be created in entity <em class="placeholder">user</em> and bundle <em class="placeholder">user</em> using the field <em class="placeholder">og_group_ref</em> as the field does not exist. in OgMembership->save() (line 50

I've tried the code on a clean install, but it gave me an identical error

More info, but no success:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1734526
https://www.drupal.org/node/1421478

Comment: Ok, the issue was caused by type error in the values array. 'entity type' must be 'entity_type'.
Now the code is error free but the nodes aren't assigned to group. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Found out removing the last line from the snippet 'node_save($node)' and the above type error was the reason for my problem. Thanks for the support.